# Using composer to install Drupal 8 on Debian 9 (Stretch)

Tags: installation, composer

I have already installed various Drupal 8 sites using composer in various environments and I am trying to do it now on a Debian 9 server>

I have done the installation in a sub-directory of /var/www/html (the standard document root on Debian 9). This directory and all directories under it are owned by root (and that is different from Debian 8 where these were owned by www-data) and readable by all other users.

Aside the standard enabled apache2 site (that I have given a servername because otherwise it captures all htpp requests to the machine), I have created a second virtual host with the following configuration file:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> ServerName xxxx.be
> ServerAdmin xxxx@gmail.com
> DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xxxx/web
> <Directory "/var/www/html/xxxx/web">
> Options FollowSymLinks
> AllowOverride All
> Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xxxx/error.log
> CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/xxxx/access.log combined
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

I have enabled the site and restarted the apache2 server. Now I want to proceed with the Drupal installation but accessing http://xxxx.be, I get:

> ```
> Internal Server Error
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
> Please contact the server administrator at xxxx@gmail.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
> More information about this error may be available in the server error.log.
> ```

In the access.log file I find:

> ```
> 192.168.178.150 - - [15/Aug/2017:19:13:28 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 583 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"
> 192.168.178.150 - - [15/Aug/2017:19:13:28 +0200] "GET /core/install.php HTTP/1.1" 500 799 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"
> ```

In the error.log file:

> ```
> [Tue Aug 15 19:13:28.611964 2017] [core:error] [pid 24071] [client 192.168.178.150:53144] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
> ```

When I try to go via the standard enabled site (http://.../xxxx/vendor/drupal/core/install.php), I get a white screen and in the access.log I see that the installation script is started but I get errors:

> ```
> [Tue Aug 15 19:25:14.592850 2017] [:error] [pid 24072] [client 192.168.178.150:53174] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/html/xxxx/vendor/drupal/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/xxxx/vendor/drupal/core/install.php on line 34
> [Tue Aug 15 19:25:14.592940 2017] [:error] [pid 24072] [client 192.168.178.150:53174] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/xxxx/vendor/drupal/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/xxxx/vendor/drupal/core/install.php on line 34
> ```

I know this must be a configuration error somewhere but I cannot find what it is.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What process did you follow for the installation? Did `composer install` get executed at any point?

Comment: Yes, and I compared the result with another Drupal 8 installation on a hosted server (of which this one is a clone) and all the necessary directories/files are present - otherwise I would also be unable to start the installation script via the standard enabled site.

Comment: I am still interested in an answer. The problem must be with changes between jessie and stretch. I replaced stretch with jessie and the installation went without problems.

Comment: I started writing a few comment replies yesterday but deleted them all, I can't help debug this without being in front of the computer with the problem, sorry